# Android Sql weird behavior on returning cursor

Tags: android, sqlite

In my db helper i have a function to return all record in the table.
The table is correctly populated.
When i run the application, it return no data.
In debug mode, stopped 1 line after query, the cursor is empty, if i open evaluate expression window and run the query function it still return no data, but if i call the function in the evaluate expression window, it return the data correctly...

Am i missing something?

```
public Cursor fetchDebCreByType(String type) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

Sorry, now it work and i don' t know why, by the way thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think because you move to the first row but you do nothing after. I don't know what you do with the cursor next, so I suggest you do something like this

```
public ArrayList<String> fetchDebCreByType(String type) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<>(); // or any other type
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        temp.add(cursor.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("somename")));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: i return a cursor for a cursorAdapter,

Comment: Try to remove the `if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }` part and see if it works then.